# Excel to PDF export using python: Getting split graphs

Tags: python, excel, pdf

While converting from EXCEL (which contains Text and graphs) to PDF, I am getting the following in PDF report(one graph broke in two different pages). 
Actual:
[image: sp1]

[image: sp2]

Expected:
[image: orig]

'''code'''

```
    def make_plot(self,chart_data):
        #see report function: add_chart(report,chart_data) that built chart_data
        try:
            subplot(111)
            subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)
            file = tempfile.mktemp(suffix=".png")
            clf() #clear plot data
            title(chart_data[1][0])
            xlabel(chart_data[1][1])
            ylabel(chart_data[1][2])
            x=chart_data[2]
            xcount=len(chart_data[2])
            ycount=xcount-3
            y = list()
            iter=0

            for ydata in chart_data:
                if iter>=3:  #y data starts on 3 array
                    y=ydata[2]
                    plot(x,y,color=chart_data[iter][1], label=chart_data[iter][0])
##                    y[:] = []
                iter=iter+1

            legend(loc=(-0.15,-0.35))
            savefig(file, bbox_inches="tight", facecolor='w', dpi=120)
            self.insert_image(file) #insert image from file into Excel
        except:
            ErrStr = "Error: make_plot(self,chart_data), " + chart_data[1][0]
            print ErrStr
            self.insert_comment(["COMMENT",ErrStr])
            print sys.exc_info()
            self.pass_status = 0
        finally:
            if(os.path.exists(file)):
                os.remove(file)

def add_chart(report,chart_data):
    #report created by ReportSetupTest("name",list)  dict [TestName][pf]
    #add_chart(report,[["Title","X Axis","Y Axis"], [x1,x2,xn],["ledged 1","color 1",[y1,y2,yn]],#["ledged 2","color 2",[2y1,2y2,2yn]],["ledged n","color n",[ny1,ny2,nyn]]])
    chartlist =list()
    chartlist=["CHART"]
    for dat in chart_data:
        chartlist.append(dat)
    report[len(report) - 1]['pf'].append(chartlist)
```

How to make actual like Expected? Is it because of code or pdf problem? The images're displayed properly in EXCEL but the problem only gets in PDF. Can someone suggest me what to do?

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: our own custom library PDF_reportlib...where it has the following libs
from win32com.client import Dispatch
excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
import tempfile
import ctypes
MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
#from autofit_columns import *
#from sheet_wrap import *
#from Cell_Adjust import *
import link_tests    
import link_checks

import pythoncom
from win32com.client import constants, Dispatch, gencache
import win32com.client.dynamic
import os,sys
import Image
import time
from pylab import *
from optparse import OptionParser
import msvcrt
import warnings

Comment: It may be something related to  "dpi=120" play with this parameter it may do the trick